# Where in .Net's DataAdapter UpdateCommand attribute is the actual SQL Command with parameters applied?

Tags: vb.net, ms-access-2010, oledbdataadapter

I'm debugging the vague "No value given for one or more required parameters" error in my VB.NET program using VB2010 Express.

I'm using command parameters, and AddWithValue, and I hope that there is some DataAdapter property that tells me what the SQL statement looks like **with the parameters applied**.

(da.UpdateCommand.CommandText just gives me my original SQL statement with parameter placeholders.)

I originally posted some code, which I ultimately debugged the old-fashioned way - by removing all parameters and then adding them back two or three at a time until the error showed up.  My bug was a mistyped fieldname.  But the code confused the issue.  I'm not looking for debugging help - I just want to know if the SQL command WITH PARAMETER VALUES exists somewhere in the very complex DataAdapter properties.

Answer (score 1):

In Access 2010 [Reports is a reserved keyword](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/access-2007-reserved-words-and-symbols-HA010030643.aspx). You need to encapsulate it in square brackets

```
strSQL = "UPDATE [Reports] SET MaxGenerations=?, " & _
         " Colwidth=?, FooterFile=?, ..." & _
         ...
```

Comment: Thanks. That answer gave me some hope, but unfortunately, it didn't solve the problem.  (And I can use Reports in SQL SELECT statements without the brackets.)  Also, I was looking for something specific - a DataAdapter attribute that give me the SQL string WITH embedded parameter values, if it exists.

Comment: Also check if the parameters are added in the collection in the same order in which their respective placeholders appears in the command text